# creating a plist file

Tags: iphone, plist

I want to write an Array to a plist wich works fine when i manually create the plist in the document folder.

but When I check if the plist exist and if not to create it from the plist in main bundle nothing happen.....

i did it as in the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) it is written.

```
NSString *plistRootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [plistRootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {

    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"];

}
```

what did I missed?

edit:

I tryed the function in an seperate App and it worked.
So I tryed It again:

```
 NString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"]; 

self.ListArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; 
NSLog(@"preSave: %@", [ListArray count]);
NSLog(@"%@", plistPath);
```

and the Log says:

```
2011-02-16 16:54:56.832 ListApp[3496:207] .../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/267F55E4-A46A-42E0-9E1C-EAF26846F75F/Documents/list.plist
```

but there is no file in the Dir.!

Comment: missing code where you actually create your array? something like array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] ?

Comment: Do you test it in simulator or on the device? Can you NSLog plistPath and paste here?

Comment: You'll need to add more information. Try adding some NSLog's of plistPath and posting the output. Are you sure the "list.plist" file is in your XCode project?

Comment: the array is there and full of data...
i tested it in the Simulator and of course your right I should have checked the plistPath for both of them.....

the path for the file if its exists is:
`2011-02-16 15:21:31.485 ListApp[2782:207] .../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/267F55E4-A46A-42E0-9E1C-EAF26846F75F/Documents/list.plist`

the path for the file if its !exists is:
`2011-02-16 15:21:31.486 ListApp[2782:207] ..../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/267F55E4-A46A-42E0-9E1C-EAF26846F75F/ListApp.app/list.plist`
how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *DocPath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

filePath=[DocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AlarmClock.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) 
{
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AlarmClock" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"file path: %@",filePath);
    NSDictionary *info=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [info writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

//*********Try this...

Answer (score 0):

I tryed the code on an other mac and there it works It's the same project.

can anyone explain me why the plist is created on one mac but not on the other?

on the IPhone also no plist is written?

I guess in both cases this is cause the array I write to the plist is empty:

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"];  
NSMutableArray *currentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];   
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
            [selectet valueForKey:NAME], @"name",
            nil];   

NSLog(@" DIC. : %@", dictionary);
[currentArray addObject:[dictionary copy]];
NSLog(@" %@", currentArray);
[currentArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
[currentArray release];
```

the dictionary has the entry but currentArray is empty....
And still it works on one mac. but not on the other and on the IPhone.

**Edit:**

For some reason it worked again.

To be sure I deleted the plist from the document folder and cleared all targets.

And now the Problem as before I can only write the plist when i write the dictionary to it but then i can only save the last one.
And reading the plist won't work either.

Can anyone Tell me why this happens and how I can solve it?

**Edit 2:**

I found the Problem: since X-Code won't create the plist when I write the array with the dictionary to the plist.When I wrote the dictionary to the plist so X-Code creates the plist but with a dictionary Root so I cant write the array to it and I also can't read it in an Array.....

I created a plist in the Resources folder with a Array Root and copy it when it not exist to document folder and now it works.....

isn't it amazing how such easy things can give you such an headache